# Changing the line color in plot_surface

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mplot3d

I did a surface plot with some data in Python.

[image]

Now I tried to change the style of such a plot. But unfortunately I am stuck in the **line color**. It's default is black, but I want to make it red or any other color.

My code is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

data=np.loadtxt("test.txt")


def formateU(data):
   U = np.zeros((20,20))
   for value in data:
      U[value[0],value[1]] = value[2]
   return U

U = formateU(data)


y,x=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0.,19,20),np.linspace(0.,19,20))

fig = plt.figure()

ax=plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x,y,U,rstride=1,cstride=1,alpha=0,linewidth=0.5)

ax.view_init(30, 45)

plt.savefig("test.png")

plt.show()
```

It' seems obvious that it has to be an additional argument in:

```
ax.plot_surface(x,y,U,rstride=1,cstride=1,alpha=0,linewidth=0.5)
```

but I can't figure it out.

Can you help me please?

The **test.txt** is available at http://www.file-upload.net/download-8564062/test.txt.html

Comment: Try `edgecolors='r'`!

Comment: [`plot_surface()`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) also takes `color` and `cmap` arguments as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How to find the required keywords:
The [plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) method creates a [Poly3DCollection](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection) which is based on [PolyCollections](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection). Latter receive the keywords like `edgecolors` (or `facecolors`).

In your example:

```py
 ax.plot_surface(x,y,U,rstride=1,cstride=1,alpha=0,linewidth=0.5, edgecolors='r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you've set the `alpha` to zero and aren't plotting the surface tiles, you might want to consider using `plot_wireframe` instead, where `color` sets the line color (rather than the tile color as in `plot_surface`).

But as Jakob suggested, `edgecolors` will also work.